# Rails error messages from models, is there a way to order them? issues with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that displays inputs for 2 models, I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

In my main model that has the accepts_nested_attributes_for, it looks like:

```
class Account <
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_user ...
```

Now in my form, I have a form_for on the `@account`, and then have `fields_for` the primary_user model.

If I hit submit, for some reason all the errors for the primary_user are displayed first.  I would rather have the errors display in the same order as the input fields on the web page.

1. Is this possible to re-order them according how they are ordered in my form_for?
2. Also, the error messages have 'primary username cannot be black', **is it possible for me to change it to 'username cannot be blank'?**  I don't really need to confuse the end user with the word 'primary' as it really doesn't make sense to them, its more of an internal thing.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the re-ordering but you can change the message for a model validations as follows:

```
validates :username,  presence: { message: "Username cannot be blank" }
```